# CheckBox and ImageButton not appearing horizontally using Android?

Tags: android, xml, checkbox

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
   <LinearLayout 
       android:id="@+id/risktablerowcheckbox_layout"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
       android:weightSum="5"
       android:visibility="gone">
    <LinearLayout 

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <CheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/risktablerow_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

        android:text="fdf dfsdfsd dfsdfsdf dfsdf sdfsdf sddfs  "
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawablePadding="2dp"/> 

     </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/risktablerowbutton_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">

<ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/riskinfo_btn" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/info_risk"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
 </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

as soon as i am placing large text in checkbox text its taking so many spaces and my button is not showing in screen in portrait mode while in lanscape button is visible here is the layout.Can someone please see the code whats wrong with above code ?

[image: Portrait Mode]

[image: horizontal Mode]

[image: after adding Keshav answer getting this layout] 
please let me know how to alignbaseline of edittext and image button and as well as spinner and imagebutton

Comment: CHECK changed answer of mine.

Comment: @keshav i have followed your answer it works but please see my last snapshots its not aligning editText and imageButton and Spinner and image button also the size of imagebutton in case of Checkbox also changes

Comment: Try to change respective weights of checkbox and imagebutton like 6:1 or 7:1

Comment: its not because of weight i am giving same weight to editText and CheckBox but checkbox image button is disturbed while edittext image button is fine while both image buttons have same weights

Comment: Please make sure that edittext and image button have same weight ratio as checkbaox and imagebutton ; and their width should be "0dp"

Comment: @keshav  i am still getting same problem because i am using <Linear with horizontal orientation><Linear with vertical orientation><textview></textview><edittext></edittext><linear><imagebutton/></linear> </linear>   is this correct approach

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43123/discussion-between-user1668447-and-keshav)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this for you check box and imagebutton :

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/risktablerow_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawablePadding="2dp"
        android:text="fdf dfsdfsd dfsdfsdf dfsdf sdfsdf sddfs sfsfsfsada "
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/riskinfo_btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First put both Imagebutton and CheckBox in single LinearLayout no need of two LinearLayout Otherwise use RelativeLayout that will be much better. Now to fix your problem set width in dp like `android:layout_width="80dp"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/risktablerow_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/riskinfo_btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawablePadding="2dp"
        android:text="fdf dfsdfsd dfsdfsdf dfsdf sdfsdf sddfs  "
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/riskinfo_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/risktablerow_checkbox"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```